# Use vue.router for redirecting to absolute path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vuetify.js

All of the examples that I can find help to manage routes inside the application like this

```
this.$router.push({name: RouteName})
```

what if I want to make redirection by absolute path? I tries

```
this.$router.push({fullPath: https://google.com})
```

But it does nothing

Comment: Simply do `location.href = 'https://google.com'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

vue-router is designed for routing within your app. It makes no sense to use it to redirect to external sites.

You can still use vue-router like this:

```
this.$router.push({ redirect: window.location.href = 'https://google.com' });
```

But it'll be better to use vanilla js:

```
window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
```

Comment: Thanks! Found this solution too:) I use document.location.href = 'fullpath';

Comment: Worth pointing out, vue-router isnt designed for routing within your app - rather, it works exclusively with relative paths. Even in-app paths do not work (feature request closed as wont implement - vanilla HTML/JS should be used instead of router).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a /404 solution, you can try this route:

```js
{
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
    name: '404',
    component: () => {
      window.location.href = 'https://errors.domain.com/404'
    }
}
```